# Wild card search to CD

Tags: bash, wildcard, cd

I'm trying to search for the first matching directory with a wildcard in a bash shell script, it seems to be working fine on a few systems, and not on others. Is there any way around this to have it work on all Centos version? I am running 6.3, then it works, but Centos 6.4 on a VPS it doesn't work, it outputs files instead of just directory:

Here is what I got:

```
DAHDI=$(ls -d -1 /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete* | head -n1);

cd "$DAHDI"
```

Any kind of help I can get on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `find` instead:

```
DAHDI=$(find /usr/src -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "dahdi-linux-complete*" | head -1)
cd "${DAHDI}"
```

Comment: Thank you for this; it really saved me from a few advil.